# C++ errors when using ios_base and ofstream

Tags: c++, file, std

```
void DataSaver::save( const std::vector<long>& vec )
{
    using std::ios_base;
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open( "/home/david/Desktop/test", ios_base::out | ios_base::binary );
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        file << vec.at( i ) << "\00\01\10\00";
    file.close();
}
```

This causes a few errors :

> g++ main.cpp datasaver.cpp
>   datasaver.cpp: In member function ‘void DataSaver::save(const std::vector&)’:
>   datasaver.cpp:11:16: error: aggregate ‘std::ofstream file’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
>   datasaver.cpp:12:41: error: incomplete type ‘std::ios_base’ used in nested name specifier
>   datasaver.cpp:12:57: error: incomplete type ‘std::ios_base’ used in nested name specifier

I included `iostream` , `ofstream` and `vector`

Can someone explain whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need

```
#include <fstream>
```

as file streams are actually defined in it